# Prime divisors in Andy Loo's proof...

Tags: prime-numbers

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2377v1.pdf I have one more question related to that proof. Look at the definition of the symbol ${s \brace r}$ (page 4). Why if $\frac{3n}{4}<p\le \frac{4n}{5}$, then $p$ divides ${2n \brace 3n/2}$? Same situation for $\frac{2n}{11}<p\le \frac{4n}{21}$ and ${4n/3 \brace n}$. Thank you in advance!
I really need your help ;D Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

When $r = 3n/2$, $s = 2n$, if $p$ satisfies$${{3n}\over4} < p \le {{4n}\over5},$$check that both $p$ and $2p$ (and no other multiple of $p$) appear in the numerator of$${s \brace r}$$(from the definition), but only $p$ (and no other multiple of $p$) appears in the denominator. So $p$ divides $${s \brace r}.$$That should get you going.